# Is there a finite number of binary-prime loops?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, binary

All natural numbers have a unique factorization into primes. I'm interested in a set $Q$ for which all natural numbers have a unique factorization into *distinct* elements of $Q$. This leads inductively to $$Q = \{p^{2^a} \mid p \textrm{ is prime}, a \in \mathbb{N}\} = \{2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,16,17,19,23, \ldots \}$$

Let $I$ index the elements of $Q$ in ascending order: $I(2) = 0$, $I(3) = 1$, $I(4) = 2$, etc.

Now consider the function $f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{N}$ which factors $n$ into distinct elements $\{q_0, q_1, \ldots, q_k \} \subset Q$ and yields $\sum_{i=0}^k 2^{I(q_i)}$. For example, $24 = 2 \times 3 \times 4$, so $f(24) = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 = 7$.

Iterating $f$ may give loops. E.g. $f(8) = 2^{I(2)} + 2^{I(4)} = 2^0 + 2^2 = 5$, and $f(5) = 2^{I(5)} = 2^3 = 8$.

My question is, is there a finite number of loops? Since all numbers can be reached by only one number, all chains are closed loops, except for the one that reaches $0$. It's feasible that the chain of numbers that goes to $0$ ($0 \leftarrow 1 \leftarrow 2 \leftarrow 3 \leftarrow 6 \leftarrow 12 \leftarrow 20 \leftarrow 28 \leftarrow \cdots$) will pass through nearly all numbers. Does it?

Comment: Are you saying that every non-prime which is not square free is now a "prime"?

Comment: Not quite. If you cannot factorize a number into 'primes' without having two of the same 'prime' in the factorization, then it's a prime. 36, for example, is not 'prime', since it is 4*9, which are 'primes'.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee OK

Comment: @InfinitePlanes, how far have you checked that chain? I find that the plausibility suffers greatly with a handful more steps: $28 \leftarrow 140 \leftarrow 260 \leftarrow 64 \leftarrow 11 \leftarrow 30 \leftarrow 420 \leftarrow 7488 \leftarrow 1922800 \leftarrow 11285855256250575 \leftarrow 54979022626732989863421863670075405480 \leftarrow 106560515672414360731061243928148028739351150682768766067946447558998761256927274137278358780926499883779557893609655274269509189496536840635167617632000$

Comment: Sadly, I have been unable to do much math on my computer lately, it isn’t feeling well. So most of what I know about this is from this question.